# Where can I find information on gas discharge tube mixes beyond the noble gases?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-chemistry, electrochemistry

I have seen plenty of information on the noble gases, and oxygen and nitrogen.

I haven't found much on other gases, or mixtures of gases.  I don't really know where to look beyond google.   I am in search of a gas or mixture that will give me a bright green.

I'm aware of Xenon/Nitrogen but it is apparently fussy and very expensive. I have no practical source of Xenon.

This information is probably something that was very popular around 1890, but may have faded off the radar lately.

It's a quantum effect, so I'm tagging it that way, but chemistry may apply.

Comment: There is a lot of information about gas mixtures in the literature about particle detectors like drift chambers, but it's not about the regime you are interested in, I am afraid (when your detector literally lights up like a neon sign, blowing fuses are not far away). I don't know if the electron and ion drift data can be used for gas discharges. Optically excited gas mixtures should be discussed in the gas laser literature. Is that where the Xenon/Nitrogen came from?

Comment: Here's an example:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jv9txBM9U5E

Comment: I'm making tubes, similar to geissler tubes, but like the one in the video, excited from one end with high frequency AC.    I have seen (rarely) references to doping a given gas with iodine or bromine, or magnesium, but no information as to how this is done.

Comment: Pretty. Well, you add a little iodine or bromine to the tube and that's it. With magnesium you will need a fairly hot discharge tube, otherwise it will condense on the walls.

Comment: There must be another step or condition.  I've tried this and had no observable results.

Comment: I see. The iodine/bromine partial pressure has to be right and you may have to control the purity of your gases with a getter before you fill the tube. The partial pressure is usually controlled trough the temperature in the tube, I believe. You may have to run a whole series of experiments at different pressures and temperatures to get the correct regime. I don't know if iodine and bromine react with electrodes and the glass... that could be a problem, too.